# load count relation for sub model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I built models and trying to retreive the count of models related with a specefic model, but the issue with the way i am using it returns me the count for all the relation.

Following is the description of my case, I have those models:

`Category` model

```
public function subcategories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\SubCategory');
}

/**
 * Get the documents for the category
 */
public function documents()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Document');
}
```

`SubCategory` model

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
}

/**
 * Get the documents for the subcategory
 */
public function documents()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Document');
}
```

I want to load the relation count between `Subcategory` and `Document` just for selected `Category`, I tried the following but it loads all the counts between `SubCategory` and `Document`:

```
Category::find($selectedCategory)->subcategories()->withCount('documents')->get()->sortBy('name');
```

Comment: Try to manually define the foreign keys in your `many to many` relation, maybe its getting the wrong foreign keys.

Comment: no it gets the right foreign key `category_id` and `subcategory_id`

Comment: Then maybe it's getting mixed up with the `documents` name in both model try to change names then try again.

Comment: I ended up making a query builder but if there is a better answer please add it here.

Comment: I'ts weird because i tried the query with similar structure to this and it gave the correct results (unless i understood the question wrong).